# Why does my system shut down when running ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting mp4 to ogg for many videos with ffmpeg but at some point during this process, my computer is shutting down.

Any idea why or how I can prevent this?

Comment: There is very little information here to provide much help. Are you using a laptop? Is it overheating? Video encoding is very CPU intensive.

Comment: no am using computer not laptop...

Comment: That does not rule out overheating which a few users have claimed to experience when performing CPU intensive commands of longer durations.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be treating this as overheating. Open a terminal, install `lm-sensors` and watch the output while you encode:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect  # say yes to everything

watch sensors
```

So do some encoding now. I predict you'll see the temperature on the CPU rocket (check your CPU's specifications for safe operating temperatures). If that can happen, your computer's current cooling solution just isn't good enough. It might just need a dust or it might need a better heatsink/fan.

This is stuff you can DIY but if you haven't done it before (or you DIY'd the current solution) it might be best to talk to a professional before you melt your CPU and/or motherboard.